# QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter ASUS vivomini un62

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, asus

I've installed ubuntu server on my asus vivomini un62, after i've installed also gnome with tasksel. The wifi is working but if i go into the settings i can't see anything for the wifi.[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3fM4.png) [screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SykcH.png)

As you can see from the screenshot from the GUI i can't see anything.

```
 lspci -knn |grep -i -A2 net 
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. AM1I-A Motherboard [1043:859e]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
--
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1043:85f2]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

```
rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
sudo dmesg | grep ath

[    7.340911] systemd[1]: Listening on multipathd control socket.
[    8.791225] ath9k 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    8.791506] ath: phy0: WB335 2-ANT card detected
[    8.791510] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[    8.800950] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[    8.802212] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
[    8.802218] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[    8.802219] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    8.802221] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    8.802223] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[    9.321580] ath9k 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I've searched a lot on internet but i can't understand why i can't see the graphical settings.
I posted some output of some command that i've read on other posts.

Comment: If you want Gnome why didn't you install standard Ubuntu desktop from the start?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm making a little server in my home, but i'm still a beginner so i wanted to install also the GUI, can i use ubuntu desktop as a server like ubuntu server?

Comment: Yes, of course you can and, again, if you want to a GUI then is preferable to start with the desktop of your preference.

Comment: Thank you @ChanganAuto, i installed ubuntu desktop everything it's fine